# Retrieving Values from array of objects

Tags: ios, swift

I have this Object Array mention below  . Can someone please guide me how can i access various values inside the Object Array.

```
CellInfo(date: "Sep 2018",
         audioFileInfos: [In.PtV.AudioFileInfo(urlString: "https://GeorgeB.m4a",
                                                    text: "9/11")
                         ])
```

i want to Access Date ,urlString and text

```
struct AudioFileInfo {
    let urlString: String
    let text: String

    init(dict: [String: String]) {
        urlString = dict["AudioFileURL"] ?? ""
        text = dict["Title"] ?? ""
    }
}

struct CellInfo {
    let date: String
    let audioFileInfos: [AudioFileInfo]
}
```

Comment: Please clearly depict the array you are trying to access.

Comment: Updated Question

Comment: it's highly depends on what `AudioFileInfo` method return type is. Please put more info i.e what is the return of the `AudioFileInfo` method is. If that is a own declared class, then does it have any text property ?

Comment: just updated  my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```
let cellInfo = CellInfo(date: "Sep 2018",
     audioFileInfos: [In.PtV.AudioFileInfo(urlString: "https://GeorgeB.m4a",
                                                text: "9/11")
                     ])
print(cellInfo.date) // prints date
print(cellInfo.audioFileInfos[0].urlString) // prints urlString
print(cellInfo.audioFileInfos[0].text) // prints urlString
```

The things is happening here is as follows

1. You create `CellInfo` struct with `date` and `audioFileInfos`.
2. while providing `audioFileInfos` you create another struct using the same way as #1
3. You pass the AudioFileInfo inside of array.
4. So incase of accessing the `date` you can directly access the `date` property using dot `.` operator.
5. For accessing the AudioFileInfo struct object, same way just with indexing added.

As `audioFileInfos` is an array, safe & complete way to access it's values is to traverse the array, meanwhile accessing the array elements.

```
for audioFileInfo in cellInfo.audioFileInfos {
    print(audioFileInfo.urlString)
    print(audioFileInfo.text)
}
```